# How to set the next state values based on previous values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is an example:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstName: 'xyz',
      lastName: 'abc';
      fullName: firstName + lastName
    };
  }
```

Trying the above technique gives me errors. I also tried using `this.firstName` and `this.lastName` but that also resulted in errors. How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: What previous values? The constructor runs when the component is first created. There is no "previous" anything.

Comment: @Quentin So there is no way to set `fullName` based on `firstName` and `lastName`?

Comment: Do it after you've create the object with just `firstName` and `lastName`

Comment: Oh, **that's** what you mean. Here's a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers with lots of existing answers.

Comment: React is completely irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. I thought it had something to do with `state`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try as below

```js
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    const firstName = 'xyz';
    const lastName = 'abc';
    
    this.state = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      fullName: firstName + lastName
    };
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use this.state.firstname.....

because you use state in constructor and if you want to access that item you have to define this.state.'your item name'

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
```

constructor(props) {
super(props);

```
const firstName = 'xyz';
const lastName = 'abc';

this.state = {
  firstName,
  lastName,
  fullName: firstName + lastName
};
```

}

on this you can use this.state.firstname

Answer (score -1):

You can set after component mounted, if your scenario allows it.

```
this.state = {
        firstName: 'xyz',
        lastName: 'abc',
        fullName: null,
    };
```

then

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        fullName : this.firstName + this.lastName
    })
}
```